# Using Prettify on dynamically-generated code

Tags: javascript, css, prettify

I'm using Prettify for syntax highlighting, but it doesn't work on dynamically generated code.

I have a form that when submitted generates code and displays it (without refreshing) in `<div id="output></div>`, but prettify doesn't work on this code, is there any workaround?

Many thanks!

Comment: How are you calling prettify?

Comment: Not exactly answer-worthy, but, try <div id="output"></div> - with the second quote-marks or whatever they're called (it's missed out from the other side of output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you recall Prettify once the new code is loaded.

You will need to add a handler to the 'Submit' event. I don't know if you are using a framework or raw JS, so I can't give a code example.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice solution at http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/syntax-highlighting-stackoverflow-google-prettify.

In short:

- listen for an event: user is inactive for X seconds (after key press)
- run the Prettify function `prettyPrint()`
- (if a user starts typing before X seconds do not run Prettify)

.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mytextarea').keydown(function() {
    $(this).stopTime();
    $(this).oneTime(1000, function() { 
      /* launch the Prettify here */
    });
  });
});
```

*code copied from http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/syntax-highlighting-stackoverflow-google-prettify*